# How to control user's activity in my website?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a website like SO. I have a trigger on the all tables (**before insert**) which checks user's status. Something like this:

```
// this line exists at the top of all triggers
@ban := select ban from user where id = new.current_id;
// new.current_id = $_SESSION['id']

// on the vote table
if ( @ban = 1 ) then
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "You cannot give vote";
endif;

// on the comment table
if ( @ban = 2 ) then
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "You cannot write comment";
endif;

// on the answer table
if ( @ban = 3 ) then
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "You cannot write answer";
endif;

// on the flag table
if ( @ban = 4 ) then
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "You cannot flag";
endif;

// on the favorite table
if ( @ban = 5 ) then
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "You cannot favorite";
endif;
```

Now I need a case to disable him to do any activity. I want to know how can I manage all user's activities? And show him something like this:

```
"You are banned and you cannot do any activity"
```

How can I implement that?

Comment: So what do you do if the user is banned from commenting *and* answering, but not from other things?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I cannot do that (banned both form *commenting* and *answering*). Because `active` column contains just one digit. `0` he can do anything. `1` he is banned from *voting* and so on...

Comment: Curious. In `if ( @ban = 1 )` and others... shouldn't that read as `if ( @ban == 1 )` ? I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not sure, but I think in MySQL one-equal operator means comparing. `.. WHERE col = 'x'`.

Comment: Curious. What's the meaning of "10-4" ?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol There is a idea: *"Don't do that in SQL side, do that in PHP side. I mean I have to fetch user's data when he logins and check his status like this `if($active == 0){ /* all fine */ }elseif ($active == 1){ /* you cannot vote */ } elseif ( .. ) { .. }`"*. Hum? Is that a good idea?

Comment: "10-4" === "understood"

Comment: @JayBlanchard . . . Oh ..! In the which dictionary it means that !!!

Comment: [Citizens Band Slang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CB_slang)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a join table, instead of storing the ban in one column within the user table.

So, you would want the following tables (only including relevant columns for simplicity):

```
USER (ID int, NAME varchar) 

BAN (ID int, NAME varchar)

User_Bans (UserID int, BanID int)
```

Then, you can select the BanIDs from the User_Bans table and concatenate messages/disable functionality appropriately.  Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I'll also add that, unless your bans are subject to change during user activity, you should load these into session upon signon, like Josh suggested.  However, I strongly disagree that you shouldn't be using SQL.  Join tables are a perfect fit for this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are doing this in SQL,

Why not just have the website pull the users data, and based of the active column  allow access or deny the the website?

if you are blocking your user from voting, viewing or what ever, based on that field just flick up the error message

When the user signs in, pull all the information you are going to need.

Username, email, image path, active field what ever. store it in the session. 
and then you never need to query that data again. unless they update it, at which point you change their session data.

Comment: Your idea is really expensive ..! *(not optimized)*

Comment: if($active != 0){
   show stuff
}else{
 show cant accsess stuff. 
} really that easy, comapred to checking each user every time they want to do something is just crazy when you can cache the result of the activity field

Comment: Fetching user's data before every request is kinda heavy.

Comment: You don't need to do it before every request, why would you? just do it when they sign in

Comment: And keep it in Sessions? hmm, can be good.. lemme think about it .. upvote anyway

Comment: Yes. you pull the users data on signing in, username email all that stuff, and activity, then you never need to check it again unless they update their information.

Comment: Only reason to pull it with every request is if the bans are volatile.  For example, if an action that the user makes can ban them from doing something, you would need to constantly check their ban status after each postback.  Otherwise, someone who was banned mid-session would be able to continue, unhindered, until their session expired.

Comment: Not all, the logic for deciding if what the user has done warrants a ban should be within the logic for the action they are doing. if they are about to get banned, change their active status and update the session. it's super easy stuff.