# How can I manage my website's users activities?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, preferences

I have a website like SO. And I have a table like this:

```
// User
+----+---------+----------------------+--------+
| id |  name   |        email         | ban    |
+----+---------+----------------------+--------+
| 1  | Peter   | peter931@hotmail.com | 0      |
| 2  | Jack    | j281_ab@gmail.com    | 2      |
| 3  | John    | black_car@yahoo.com  | 1      |
+----+---------+----------------------+--------+
```

When user log in, I store `ban` column's value in the `$_SESSION['ban']`. And I have this conditions:

```
if ( $ban == 0 ) {
    echo 'He has no limits and can do anything in this website';
} elseif ( $ban == 1 ) {
    echo 'He can do anything except voting';
} elseif ( $ban == 2 ) {
    echo 'He can do anything except commenting';
} elseif ( $ban == 3 ) {
    echo 'He can do anything except answering';
} elseif ( $ban == 4 ) {
    echo 'He can do anything except asking';
} elseif ( $ban == 5 ) {
    echo 'He can do anything except favpriting';
} elseif ( $ban == 6 ) {
    echo 'He can do anything except flagging';
} else {
    echo 'He is totally banned from everything and he isn't able to do any activity here';
}
```

As you see, I can control my website's users based on`ban`-column's value.

---

**What's my question?**

My algorithm just let me to ban my website's user in either only one case *(or voting, or commenting or flagging or ..)* or all cases together *(voting and commenting and flagging and ...)*.

In other word, a user can be:

- no ban
- ban from everything
- ban in only one field

I mean I cannot ban a user from both *voting* and *commenting*. How can I improve my algorithm and implement banning for two cases, or three cases?

Comment: 1) Look at how file permission does this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Numeric_notation 2) Use an array where you store: `ban => can't do` and then use the array instead of this long if/else

Comment: Look up "Bitmasks in PHP"

Comment: @JasonSperske I did, thx. Just as a advise, may you please tell me what's your opinion about [doing that by triggers in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053960/how-to-control-users-activity-in-my-website) *(instead of PHP)*